# What is the Windows hotkey to minimise a single, currently active window?

Tags: windows-vista, hotkeys

On Windows Vista, I'm familiar with <kbd>[image: Windows Key] Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to show the desktop but sometimes I just want to minimise two or three windows as they become active and not the whole lot.

What hotkey can I use to minimise only the currently active window?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

I've been using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>N</kbd> for years. Works on any Windows version, all the way back to Windows 3.0! It should work with all keyboard layouts and probably even all Windows localizations.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> opens the general windows menu. You can open it manually by left-clicking with the mouse on the top left window corner.

The menu contains the options to maximize, minimize, close the window, etc. It also underlines the key you need to press to select the appropriate option ("miNimize").

The <kbd>N</kbd> is not a general "hotkey" but an access key – a keyboard shortcut to an entry in a GUI menu that works **only if/after** the menu opens. The menu items texts differ across localizations (languages), which is why a different letter might be underlined and serve as the access key.

Comment: This pauses alot of streaming audio sites (spacebar is culprit)

Comment: Does not work if current language/layout is not English.

Comment: But one can make hotkey to switch to English and then execute alt+space-N.

Comment: Duh. Hit Alt+Space and see what the keyboard shortcut is in your language.

Comment: They changed the hotkeys per language? Disturbing...

Comment: Doesn't work if the window is in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @Timo It's hard to press the N key if your keyboard [lacks an N key](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Keyboard_Layout_Sanskrit.png). Considering there is more than one keyboard layout in existence (and use), I would hope they do change hotkeys to fit the language or keyboard.

Comment: @8bittree Lol, fair point! Nevertheless, I hope they have focused on maintaining easy positioning of the most common hotkeys.

Comment: @8bittree that is not why, it's because the shortcut relates to the native word; otherwise the keystrokes would be the same in all of Europe (QWERTY, QWERTZ and AZERTY keyboards). In Portuguese Windows/Office: ctrl+a opens ("abrir"), and ctrl+t selects all ("tudo")... ctrl+n bolds ("negrito")...; we have all the letters from the English keyboard and then some (ç«» etc).

Comment: @ANeves You seem to be confirming exactly what I said: that the hotkeys should and do change to fit the keyboard and language.

Comment: As a guy coming from Mac this sucks.  CMD + H is all it takes.  No 3 key or 2 step process.  And it works the same in all apps unlike windows where sometimes this does weird stuff.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey you cannot compare as MacOS belongs to the Unix family :-)

Comment: It doesn't work on maximized borderless windows (games for instance)

Answer (score 196):

A small workaround is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> – it doesn't minimize the active window but places it behind all other windows. The effect is similar however.

I know it's not precisely what the question asker wanted, but it's a built-in Windows one-step solution that works in a similar way.

Comment: I like your solution the most because it requires the least amount of keystrokes and can be done with only the left hand! If all your windows are maximized, this achieves almost the same effect.

Comment: One downside to this is not being able to Alt+Tab back to it. The ideal is likely to have a hotkey that brings the window just behind to the front.

Comment: No it isn't. If you use Alt+Esc, you can get that window back with Alt+Tab as usual. At least for Windows 10 it is the case.

Comment: Thank you, now I can parry between Alt Tab and Alt Esc

Comment: Wow. That is even better, because what I usually want is to get it out of the way and/or access the window behind it. And it even leaves the Alt+Tab switching order intact! You have made my day.

Comment: On multiple displays this is not sufficient because a window might be the only one on a specific display and can't disappear behind another window (althought I still want it to be minimized so it doesn't attract attention)

Comment: @Andrew the exactly opposite to "Alt+Esc" is the "Alt+Esc+Shift" which brings to the front the furthermost Back-placed window.

Answer (score 104):

In Windows 7 and later you can minimize the currently active window with: <kbd>**Win**</kbd>+<kbd>**Down**</kbd>.

(This may be an Aero feature that works with Vista as well.)

Comment: Note that you have to have Aero Snap enabled for this to work.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://aerosnap.de/index_eng.htm ? Even with this on vista windows-down arrow only seems to work with about half the windows. alt-space n is a lot more reliable.

Comment: Doesn't work on any window that is maximised, or snapped to half a screen.

Comment: @Coxy It's a 2 step process if it's maximized or snapped. First stroke restores it to original form, second stroke minimizes it. Not very comfortable.

Comment: @buffer Not only is it a 2-step process, but your window has also lost its maximized state when you go back to it. :(

Comment: If active window is in full screen mode, then this hotkey won't work!

Comment: doesn't work in win 10

Comment: It is a 3-step process in Windows 10

Comment: It was mentioned above basically this will go down to Restore or none full screen mode first so you do it twice. Unfortunately it will potentially scramble the widows frames and alignment which is worse then mousing over to the corner. Glad to find ALT-Space N now though ALT-ESC is also a good option.

Answer (score 66):

When maximized:

- Windows key + press the down arrow twice.

When not maximized:

- Windows key + press the down arrow once.

Comment: What's the difference between pressing once and twice? Pressing this once was already mentioned…

Comment: @slhck I don't think there is a difference. Pressing once minimizes the window that currently has focus, and moves the focus to another window. Pressing again simply minimizes that window, etc. etc.

Comment: Actually Ricky is (with condition) right. Pressing Win+Down when a window is maximized will not minimize it, but only restore it down. You have to press  Win+Down once more in order to minimize it.

Comment: For my Win10 computer it takes four down arrows

Answer (score 26):

AutoHotKey script for Minimize:

```
;=============================================================================;
; WINDOWS KEY + Alt + Down  --  Minimizies Active window
;=============================================================================;
; instead of "Restore Down" for Win+Down
#!Down::WinMinimize, A
```

Explanation:

- Format: `[Key-Combination]::[Action]`
- `#!Down` - will execute when Windows-Key (`#`), Alt-Key (`!`), Down-Arrow-Key (`down`) are pressed together
- `WinMinimize, A` will mimimize (`WinMinimize`) the active (`A`) window

Comment: This doesn't work when I use the alt key.

Comment: Perfect, works for me!

Comment: In v.2.0 following script worked for me:
```#!Down::WinMinimize "A"```

Answer (score 14):

according to [microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449), there isn't one, but it is easily scripted in [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml).

EDIT: Below is a very very basic sample of how to accomplish a hotkey to minimize the focused window, fully commented.

```
#include <WinApi.au3> ;include winAPI library

HotKeySet("!M",'_MinimizeActive') ;sets hotkey to Alt+Shift+m to trigger function

While 1 ;loop to keep alive

WEnd

Func _MinimizeActive()
    Local $v_Wnd, $w_Wnd ;declare variables
    $v_Wnd = _WinAPI_GetFocus() ;get focused window
    $w_Wnd = WinGetHandle($v_Wnd) ;get handle of focused window
    WinSetState($w_Wnd,"",@SW_MINIMIZE) ;minimize focused window
EndFunc
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, the link the Microsoft hotkeys, and what looks like a free solution!

Comment: just added a basic template for what you're looking for, coded in autoit.

Comment: Why a downvote? It is a viable solution and also can be customized to do a lot more than just the focused window. In a lot of ways, this can be far superior to the accepted answer, depending on preferences of OP (such as selecting the topmost 3 windows and isolate out certain ones that he/she never wants minimized and minimize the rest).

Answer (score 14):

If what you want is an easy way to open and minimize a window you use often, just pin it to the task bar and move it to one of the first positions. Then you can use `Windows`+`1`, `2`, `3` etc. to quickly toggle the window.

No more scrolling through loads of windows with ´Alt´+´Tab´ to maximize it again either.

Comment: This works well, but only if it's the only window open from that application. E.g. I'm trying to minimize a browser window and switch to the one behind it and they're both from the same browser and it instead brings up peek (and selecting a new window won't minimize the current one).

Answer (score 1):

Because windows doesn't have a shortcut key for it, you may use a 3rd party solution, like autoit to do that.

Below is a simple script for it. This first to set a hotkey (with [HotKeySet()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/HotKeySet.htm)), than minimize current window (with [WinSetState()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinSetState.htm)).

```
#include <WinApi.au3>

HotKeySet("!M",'MinimizeWin') ;Alt+Shift+m

While 1
Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func MinimizeWin()
    WinSetState("[ACTIVE]", "", @SW_MINIMIZE)
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is also *another two-step solution*, but I find it more nerve-friendly as it clears everything from my mind on the first step:

1. <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>: Minimize All Windows
2. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>: Choose A Window You Want To Work With

Comment: The task: minimize a single window. Your answer: minimize all but one. Does not fit. What am I missing?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You are right indeed, it doesn't exactly answer what the OP has asked for, but I believe many people come here (this is my second time, personally) because they find `win+downarrow+win+downarrow` redundant and repetitive. All I want is to minimize some window I don't need so that it's closed in my mind too. So I think using `win + D` or `win + m` to minimize all windows, is not that bad, if it's followed by `alt + tab`.

Comment: My solution was: upgrade to Linux. Problem solved!