# How to minimize all windows in current screen under Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I sometimes run full-screen applications in the external screen and I don't want to minimize them when I pressing `winkey + d` when I'm working on the main screen.

Under Windows 7, I can use `winkey + m` to minimize all windows in *current* screen. But for Windows 8.1, `winkey + m` works exactly the same as `winkey + d`.

This is really inconvenient for me, especially when the applications which are in the external one are running in exclusive mode.

So is there a hotkey acts the same as `winkey + m` under Windows 7 for 8? Or is there any softwares which can do this for me?

Comment: Winkey + M minimizes all windows on *all* screens on my Windows 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> should minimise the selected Explorer window.

If that doesn't work, you could [minimise the selected windows separately](https://superuser.com/questions/189194/what-is-the-windows-hotkey-to-minimise-a-single-currently-active-window) with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

[Here's](https://superuser.com/questions/348423/minimize-all-windows-on-the-active-monitor) the same question asked but for Windows 7. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> seems to minimise **all** windows instead of those only on the active screen for most.

Apparently for the others (and possibly in your case) it was due to [Actual Multiple Monitors](http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/) which had a `Minimize All command affects only the monitor with mouse` option to choose. That's probably what you want to look for.

[image]

Comment: It's just what I need but it's a little expensive for my simple requirement. I'd like to wait for another day to see if there're better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the very right end of the Task Bar (Lower right corner of your screen) with your mouse. This is a toggle button that will minimize all currently open windows and restore them every time you click on it. Not a keyboard solution, but it works.