# Minimize all windows on only one monitor in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

How to minimize all windows on only one monitor in Windows 10?

I know about the nice option in windows 7, which called: 
"Minimize All command affects only the monitor with mouse".
But can not find analog in Windows 10.

Comment: Grab a window and shake it with the mouse

Comment: @Ramhound - Shaking a window closes all windows on all monitors, not just the active one.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf - "How to minimize all windows on the active monitor in Windows 10?" - **What exactly is your point?**

Comment: I would like to point out that, Windows Logo+M, is a keyboard specific feature (Microsoft Natural Keyboard) that still works in Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound - My point is that the OP wants to minimize all windows on the **active** monitor, the one that has the mouse cursor, **not** the windows on all monitors.

Comment: Are you referring to http://superuser.com/a/931393/259665 ? If so then you need to buy the software in order to get that functionality. In Windows 7 the Win+m combination minimizes all windows on all monitors.