# Direct shortcut for Windows Maximize/Minimize/Restore window?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, shortcuts, productivity

Is there a direct shortcut for maximizing/minimizing/restoring current window in Windows (10)?

I know I can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then use the arrows to navigate and select, but I looking for a direct shortcut.

Comment: Actually you can Alt+Space, X to maximize etc. No need for arrow keys and navigation.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

From Help Docs on [**Keyboard shortcuts in Windows**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec):

| Shortcut | Action |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> | Display the desktop. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> | Minimize all windows. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> | Restore minimized windows to the desktop. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> | Maximize the window. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> | Maximize the window to the left side of the screen. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> | Maximize the window to the right side of the screen. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> | Minimize the window. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> | Minimize all but the active window. |
| <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> | Stretch the window to the top and bottom of the screen. |

Comment: The Win+Down was a new one to me. I have always used Alt+Space, `n` (because `n` is the hotkey for *Minimize*), but this is language-dependent.

Comment: Win+Down doesn't minimize a maximized window to tray directly, it first "unsnaps" the window, you have to press again for the window to be minimized to tray.

Comment: ^^ This. and then if you double-tap the down-arrow, it means it will only restore back to a floating-window. Wish there was a single-tap combo to always minimise.

Comment: A quick edit with the same commands for Linux would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: @Darkov That would be very difficult. Linux has several window managers and desktop environments, and in my experience not all of them come with a lot of keyboard shortcuts preconfigured, but offer ways to configure them by the user.

Comment: I think the drawback to these hot keys is that they aren't one handed.  I'm not sure if there's a similar Windows tool, but Spectacle on OSX has simple one handed shortcuts for window management that are much quicker to press, and you don't have to take a hand off the mouse.  For example cmd+option+f to maximize a window.

Comment: I use Windows in a virtual machine on my Mac. I am always pressing <kbd>⌘←</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line, only to find the window moving to the left of the screen. The <kbd>Win↑</kbd> will be a great help. BTW I find that I have to do that in two steps: the first time moves the window to the top left corner.

Comment: As not to cause confusion, I would suggest that it be mentioned somewhere in the answer that these are hotkeys for Window's **Window Snapping** feature, and thus do not perform an exclusive action (most of them AFAIK either toggle or cycle through different states).

Comment: The Win+Shift+M shortcut is new to me.  Is there some functional difference between that and untoggling Win+D?  My computer isn't accessible to me at the moment.

Comment: @AndyFraley Not really a drawback in my opinion, since you don't really need them often enough (or at least I don't).  Even not having them at all isn't *that* bad, to be honest.

Answer (score 8):

Currently as per my experience in Windows 10:

Restore Down The Maximized Window **OR** Minimize The Restored Window
 
**Win + Down Arrow**

Minimize The Maximized Window
**Win + Down Arrow (twice)**

Maximize The Restored Window
**Win + Up Arrow**

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same thing, and I want to refer to [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1053039/321990) by [Sam Hasler](https://superuser.com/users/772/sam-hasler) who made an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script that adds a shortcut for that task.

In short, this is the script (you need [ahk](https://www.autohotkey.com/)) - just save it as an `.ahk` file and put it in the startup folder (open it with `shell:startup` from the `Run`):

```
;=========================================================;
; WINDOWS KEY + Alt + Down  --  Minimizies Active window
;=========================================================;
; instead of "Restore Down" for Win+Down

#!Down::WinMinimize, A
```

For more details, go to the [referred answer](https://superuser.com/a/1053039/321990).

Comment: I love this shortcut and also having #!::WinMaximizze, A because doing Win+Up will often requires to execute the shortcut twice because the first time, the window will not automatically be maximized but put in the top right corner if the window previously docked to the side. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (shown above, as "Restore minimized windows to the desktop.") is in Windows 11 only. The other listed shortcuts work in Windows 10, and likely older versions of Windows as well.

I would appropriately share that info as a comment on the near-perfect answer above . . . but I just need another 49 pts / 490 years seeing as how I've been on stack intermittently for 10, now. Just thank me for not complaining until today, and for never having spammed the forum with questions that have already been answered 500 times.

Comment: Its still an answer and have upvoted it. However. you can make it better by explaining in ypur answer, exactly what that shortcut does - MAX. MIN OR RESIZE

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Powertoys Fancyzones](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys), you have to set the setting PowerToys->FancyZones->Override Windows Snap->"Move windows based on: Zone index" to be able to maximize/minimize using `Win`+`Up`/`Down`.

There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/13162) to be able to maximize while using the setting "Move windows based on: Relative Position".

Comment: does not seem to work anymore? at least with "Move windows based on: Relative Position"

Comment: @gooleem Same. If you go into powertoys settings->fancyzones->override windows snap->move windows based on: Zone Index, then maximizing using windows shortcuts works.
If you still want to move by relative position, there is an [open feature request for that](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/13162). I will update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Why you make it so difficult? Make a shortcut to this.

```
C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}
```

Done. (you can change the ICON if you want).
Works for me the ol' windows7 desktop button.

Comment: Your answer is a bit terse, you could improve it by explaining why this works, what is that GUID etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).