# Shortcut to immediately minimize a window? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I found `WinKey + DownArrow`, which does work, but it takes multiple presses. (If the focused application is full screen, `WinKey + DownArrow` will make it windowed on the first press, snap it to the right on the second press, maximize it to the right on the third press, snap it down on the fourth press, and then finally minimize it on the fifth press. Clearly not very convenient if the only goal is to minimize.)

`WinKey + M` and `WinKey + D` also works, but it minimizes all open windows as opposed to just the open one.

Are there any other shortcuts that minimizes just the focused window? If not, how might one go about adding this shortcut on their own?

Comment: I don't think one exists, as you've described. Theres [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/189194/what-is-the-windows-hotkey-to-minimise-a-single-currently-active-window/189235) that has some other workarounds for you. It mentions Vista, but the answers are still good for 10.

Comment: @Karu Thank you! I hadn't seen that thread somehow and I found `Alt+Escape` on it which is pretty much perfect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way without adding or changing anything would be `Alt`+`Space`+`n`. And if you would like to see any other options you can press `Alt`+`Space` and see available option. For example to maximize window it'd be `x` and to close it'd be `c`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this!